# sed extract text between two xml tags with case insensitive

Tags: bash, shell, centos7

I want to get the String between tag with case insensitive.

**Sample.xml:**

`<Sample>
    <emp>
        <id>1234</id>
        <name>Raj</name>
    </emp>
</Sample>`

Or

`<Sample><emp><id>1234</id><name>Raj</name></emp></Sample>`

I did like below that is working fine but not case insensitive.

```
sed -n 's:.*<name>\(.*\)</name>.*:\1:p' Sample.xml
```

Here `name` is case insensitive, how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
sed -n 's:.*<namE>\(.*\)</Name>.*:\1:pgI' Sample.xml
```

Comment: This is still case-sensitive.

Comment: No this is not case sensitive. I tired all cases.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an xml-aware utility when processing XML documents. `sed` and `awk` do not provide any means of validating XML. For example, using `xmlstarlet` you would use:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/Sample/emp/name" Sample.xml
```

(**note:** node names with `xmlstarlet` are case-sensitive. Query the XML structure for proper case before use)

Which would retrieve `Raj` as the output.

If you did want to use `sed` (not recommended), you could do:

```
sed 's/^.*<naME>\([^<]*\)<\/name>.*$/\1/gI' Sample.xml
```

(**note:** you were essentially missing the anchors `'^'` and `'$'` anchoring the beginning and end of line. This `sed` expression only works if the XML is all on the same line, a proper XML utility has no such restriction)

The output is the same.

Comment: Where do you make it case-insensitive?

Comment: this is not answered  my quotation.. I need **case insensitive**

Comment: Then use the `sed` option above -- it is case-insensitive.

Comment: My xml is formatted one, here i put it in single line `sed` is not working for formatted xml.

Comment: I put your input in the file `Sample.xml` all on one line like you show and the output is `Raj` every time - - are you on LInux, Mac, Windows WSL -- do you have GNU `sed` or something different. The `sed` above doesn't contain anything that should be GNU specific, so I'm not sure what the issue is. If your file is from windows and is UTF-16 -- that will be a problem. What does `file Sample.xml` show?

Comment: I edited my question. `sed -n 's:.*<namE>\(.*\)</Name>.*:\1:pgI' Sample.xml` this is working for both single line xml or formatted xml.

Comment: The important point is `"<name>Raj</name>"` being all on one line. Yes `sed` will still work there, but not with `"<name>\n\tRaj\n</name>\n"`. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

An xslt template can be used to normalize case before selecting with xmlstarlet. Note that the elements in the xpath are now all lowercase.

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/sample/emp/name" <(xsltproc element-name-tolower.xsl Sample.xml)
```

element-name-tolower.xsl:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:variable name="elemName" select="translate(name(.), $uppercase, $lowercase)"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$elemName}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample.xml:

```xml
<Sample>
    <emp>
        <id>1234</id>
        <nAme>Raj</nAme>
    </emp>
</Sample>
```

Output:

```
Raj
```